# Why do I have to call model.predict(x) instead of model(x)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following keras model:

```
def model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM, name='model_1'):

model = Sequential(name=name)

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size+1, output_dim=output_dim, mask_zero=True, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))

model.add(LSTM(units=rnn_units, input_shape=input_shape_LSTM, 
    stateful=True, 
    return_sequences=True, 
    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
    recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(units=vocab_size))

return model
```

I then have the vector x_ and y_ given by:

```
x_, y_ = get_batches(X, y, batch_size)
x_shape: (32, 200000)
y_ shape: (32, 200000)
```

Now, I do not understand why if I call:

```
model.predict(x_)
```

I get the predicted array as expected.

Instead, if I call:

```
model(x_)
```

the following error appears:

```
ValueError: Layer model_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[    0,     0,     0, ..., 21839, 21841,  9579],
   [    0,     0,     0, ...,     1,     1, 23012],
   [    0,     0,     0, ...,   246,  9832,  9832],
   ...,
   [    0,     0,     0, ..., 24827, 24867, 24868],
   [    0,     0,     0, ..., 22448, 22426, 22426],
   [    0,     0,     0, ...,     1,     1,     1]])]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Can someone explain me why? I red the suggested questions for this topic and I didn't find the answear...

Comment: why you are calling model but not its method such as model.fit()? What is your desired output?

Comment: @muhammad if you do model(x) it is the same as doing model.call(x).

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict)

> This [predict] method is designed for performance in large scale inputs. For small amount of inputs that fit in one batch, directly using **call** is recommended for faster execution, e.g., model(x), or model(x, training=False)

If you are unfamiliar with python's magic functions, using `my_object(x)` is equivalent to writing `my_object.__call__(x)`.

So, how does this quote apply to your case?

The model by extension is also a `tf.keras.layer.Layer`, that's why you can stack multiple models into higher level models. Because it is also a layer, when you call it like `model(x)`, it is acting like a layer and just returns transformed inputs, nothing more. But when you call it like `model.predict(x)`, it acts more like a model and gives you transformations in the way that is more useful when predicting with model.

Why does the exception occur?

Because the `Embedding` layer is expecting a `tf.Tensor` and calling the model with `model(x)` does not perform that conversion. You can do it manually with `tf.constant([array])` and then it will work. Or, you could add the `tf.keras.layers.Input` layer at the start and it will also solve the problem.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your code. You don't give the parameter values/input values and it's not clear what tensorflow functions you are trying to use. This is what I tried

```
import tensorflow as tf

def model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM, name='model_1'):

    model = tf.keras.Sequential(name=name)

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size+1, output_dim=output_dim, mask_zero=True, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=rnn_units, input_shape=input_shape_LSTM,
        stateful=True,
        return_sequences=True,
        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
        recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=vocab_size))

    return model

model = model_1(100, 50, (32,5), 10, (32,50))

x = tf.convert_to_tensor( np.random.rand(32,5) )
y = tf.convert_to_tensor( np.random.rand(32,5))

test = model(x)

test2 = model.predict(x)
```

And it works as expected, with no errors (Note test and test2 are not going to be equal because you have stateful = True to the LSTM)

Comment: That is not an answer.

Comment: How is this not an answer? Op's code doesn't run copy pasted, I modified it a bit, and showed that model.predict and model.call basically do the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you have taken input_shape argument in your lstm layer, which is an intermediate layer,

Try this

```
def model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, name='model_1'):

model = Sequential(name=name)

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size+1, output_dim=output_dim, mask_zero=True, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))

model.add(LSTM(units=rnn_units, 
    stateful=True, 
    return_sequences=True, 
    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
    recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(units=vocab_size))

return model
```

this is working for me, full working code [here](https://pastebin.com/j3GDreKK)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your answears! I found the problem and I'll share with you so maybe I't will be usefull also for others (and maybe you can also explain me!)

I've imported tensorflow and the following layers:

```
  import tensorflow as tf
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Embedding
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import Dropout
    from keras.layers import LSTM

# create and fit the model

rnn_units = 1024
output_dim = 256
batch_size = 32
vocab_size = unique_columns.shape[1]
batch_input_dims = [batch_size, None]
input_shape_LSTM = (X.shape[1], 1)
# X has shape (200, 200000) and it is a numpy.ndarray
```

Then, I've built two models. The first one with the imported layers:

```
def model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM, name='LSTM_1'):
    
    model = Sequential(name=name)
    
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size+1, output_dim=output_dim, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))
    
    return model
```

And the second one with tf.keras.layers

```
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size, batch_input_dims, name='LSTM_2'):
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(name=name)
   
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))
        
    return model
```

Then I've built the two models:

```
      model = build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim=output_dim, rnn_units=rnn_units,batch_size=batch_size, batch_input_dims=batch_input_dims)
model.summary()

Model: "LSTM_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (32, None, 256)           6522112   
=================================================================
Total params: 6,522,112
Trainable params: 6,522,112
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And

```
model_LSTM = model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM)
model_LSTM.summary()
Model: "LSTM_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (32, None, 256)           6522112   
=================================================================
Total params: 6,522,112
Trainable params: 6,522,112
Non-trainable params: 0


model_LSTM = model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM)
```

Finally, if I try to feed an input like X[:batch_size,:]

```
model(X[:32,:])
tf.Tensor: id=28, shape=(32, 200, 256), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        ...,
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ]],...]]]
```

On the other hand, If I call `model_LSTM(X[:batch_size,:]`I get the original error:

```
ValueError: Layer LSTM_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        5.30201869e-03, 2.12080748e-03, 3.92742126e-05],
       ...,
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        5.33383081e-01, 5.33383081e-01, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        1.99395177e-01, 1.99395177e-01, 1.99395177e-01]])]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

**Can someone explain this behavior??**

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27018895)

Comment: I posted here because it is strictly related with my original question

Comment: This answer went through the Low Quality Review Queue because it looks like a new, follow-up question to your original question. Stack Overflow does not have a forum or thread format (take the [tour]). It has a Q&A format, post a Q and people will post A's. It is also unlikely that people would see your new question because it is in the Answers section. That is why I recommend posting it as a new question, and then "*Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.*". Also read [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/2745495).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I'll post a new question and ill take the "tour", have a nice day