# Weird tensorflow behaviour on simple models

Tags: python, tensorflow

while solving another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583021/why-do-i-have-to-call-model-predictx-instead-of-modelx/63586447?noredirect=1#comment112451129_63586447) i wrote these lines of code and I got a weird output.

I've imported tensorflow and the following layers:

```
  import tensorflow as tf
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Embedding
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import Dropout
    from keras.layers import LSTM

# create and fit the model

rnn_units = 1024
output_dim = 256
batch_size = 32
vocab_size = unique_columns.shape[1]
batch_input_dims = [batch_size, None]
input_shape_LSTM = (X.shape[1], 1)
# X has shape (200, 200000) and it is a numpy.ndarray
```

Then, I've built two models. The first one with the imported layers:

```
def model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM, name='LSTM_1'):
    
    model = Sequential(name=name)
    
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size+1, output_dim=output_dim, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))
    
    return model
```

And the second one with tf.keras.layers

```
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size, batch_input_dims, name='LSTM_2'):
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(name=name)
   
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=batch_input_dims))
        
    return model
```

Then I've built the two models:

```
      model = build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim=output_dim, rnn_units=rnn_units,batch_size=batch_size, batch_input_dims=batch_input_dims)
model.summary()

Model: "LSTM_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (32, None, 256)           6522112   
=================================================================
Total params: 6,522,112
Trainable params: 6,522,112
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And

```
model_LSTM = model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM)
model_LSTM.summary()
Model: "LSTM_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (32, None, 256)           6522112   
=================================================================
Total params: 6,522,112
Trainable params: 6,522,112
Non-trainable params: 0


model_LSTM = model_1(vocab_size, output_dim, batch_input_dims, rnn_units, input_shape_LSTM)
```

Finally, if I try to feed an input like X[:batch_size,:]

```
model(X[:32,:])
tf.Tensor: id=28, shape=(32, 200, 256), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        ...,
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ],
        [-0.02251144, -0.00920795, -0.01335046, ..., -0.00379463,
          0.00821525, -0.0356279 ]],...]]]
```

On the other hand, If I call `model_LSTM(X[:batch_size,:]`I get the original error:

```
ValueError: Layer LSTM_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        5.30201869e-03, 2.12080748e-03, 3.92742126e-05],
       ...,
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        5.33383081e-01, 5.33383081e-01, 3.92742126e-05],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        1.99395177e-01, 1.99395177e-01, 1.99395177e-01]])]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

**Can someone explain this behavior??**

Comment: Does the error go away when you use `tf.convert_to_tensor` on `X` before passing it in `model_LSTM(X[:batch_size,:]`? If so, that error is same as in previous question.

Comment: Yes the error goes away.. Anyhow, why with the import of the layers this error pops up and, instead, if I build the model with tf.keras.layers I cann pass the model the numpy array?

Comment: See my answer below, please.

Answer (score 0):

Does the error go away when you use `tf.convert_to_tensor` on X before passing it in `model_LSTM(X[:batch_size,:]`? If so, that error is same as in your previous question.

If you pass in a tensor, everything will usually work fine. But if you pass in anything other than a tensor, like python array or numpy array, it has to convert to a tensor *somewhere*. Tensorflow only works internally with its `tf.Tensor`s.

So, if you pass a non-tensor value somewhere API only expects to see tensors, it will try to do tensor operations on your numpy array and you will get an error.

So, for any kind of `All inputs to the layer should be tensors` or `variable has no attribute foobar` The first thing you should do is try to pass in a well-formed tensor. Usually, this will get rid of the exception.

Also note that you should always import keras and its layers like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import someModule
```

Not

```py
from keras import someModule
```

This is because if you also have a separate `keras` installed (not tf.keras), it will not work with `tf.Tensor` and might cause confusion afterwards. Be precise about where you are importing the keras API from. There are many implementations of `keras` API. For example, see [this](https://jonwood.co/blog/2018/4/16/using-cntk-as-a-backend-for-keras) implementaion of keras API.

Does this answer help?

Comment: This was clear from the answear you gave me in other question,thanks. Here I was just interested in understanding why two models that look the same but vary only in the way the keras layers are imported differ in their behavior. (I understood that in one way there is a numpyarray to tensor transformation but I do not understanjd where given that the two models should be the same).

Comment: Yes! super useful!!

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but can you mark my answer as accepted? 
Only in case it helped you resolve your problem. 
Thanks and sorry for asking you this.